# Lazy load images when they come into the viewport

Tags: jquery, image, lazy-loading

I've been coming across blogs/websites lately that only load images when they are scrolled into the visible viewport.  It then fades them in.  Is there a jQuery ... even Wordpress plug-in that does this?

e.g. http://icodeblog.com

Comment: Seems really annoying to the user...

Comment: Double-dupe! I alone have answered this very question twice on SO.

Comment: Dupe 1 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1464968/load-content-as-an-element-scrolls-into-view

Comment: Dupe 2 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2171889/jquery-infinite-scrolling-lazy-loading

Comment: Can't find the rest right now but if I remember correctly, LazyLoad was the top candidate in all those questions.

Comment: @pekka, I can't possibly see any correlation between these questions about content and lazy loading images.

Comment: @Nissan Fan uhh... "Load content as element scrolls into view"? And the second question has LazyLoad as the accepted answer? What more correlation do you need? :)

Comment: @Pekka I am not asking about HTML lazy loading.  I'm talking about images specifically.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One of the good things about JavaScript is you can view source and look at whats going on. After viewing the source I found this:

http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload

Answer (score 2):

LazyReady: http://plugins.jquery.com/project/LazyReady

Comment: Page doesn't exist anymore.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this jQuery plugin I wrote that uses html comments to lazy load any arbitrary bits of html, including images:

[jQuery Lazy Loader Blog Post](http://ivorycity.com/blog/2011/04/19/jquery-lazy-loader-load-html-and-images-on-scroll/)

[jQuery Lazy Loader Plugin Page](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/LazyLoadOnScroll)

Here's an example:

```
<pre class=”i-am-lazy” ><!–
    <img src=”some.png” />
 –></pre>

<pre class=”i-am-lazy” ><!–
    <div>Any, html css img background, whatever. <img src=”some.png” /> </div>
–></pre>

<script type=”text/javascript” src=”jquery.lazyloader.js” ></script>
<script type=”text/javascript” >
$(document).ready( function()
{
    $(’pre.i-am-lazy’).lazyLoad();
});
</script>
```

So basically you wrap the content you want to lazy load with a placeholder tag and and inner html comment. When the placeholder becomes visible in the viewport, it is replaced with the html string inside the comment.

You can use any tag for the placeholder but I like pre because it renders as 0 dimension when there's only a comment inside.

Hope this helps!
@MW_Collins